# New Timeline Tab/Page width

Tags: facebook, tabs, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

With the new App Pages on a Facebook Apps Timeline is there any way to remove the 20px white border around the iframe?

Here is an example page, https://www.facebook.com/Firefox/app_219601608073693

Answer (score 1):

If you make **your** background white then there are not really borders ;)

But in all seriousness - what you could do is use a "Wide (810px)" layout for your tab app and then create a smaller centered div element in which you can contain your entire application.

Eg:

```
<div style="width:520px; margin:0 auto;">
  Your 520px centered content appears here!
</div>
```

<sub>Please don't be lazy like me :)  Don't use inline styles.</sub>

Other than that I do not believe that there is a way to remove or customize any of Facebook's styling inside a timeline/page app...

Comment: I wanted to have an image as a background but it didn't look good with a 20px white border. Thanks for your help though, I'm going to leave this question up for a while to see if anyone else has thought of a clever solution for this.

Comment: There are several javascript calls which can alter the facebook styling but I can't seem to find hardly any documentation on the new timeline/app page style.